# Perform addition, replace in XML node in a text file using power shell

Tags: sql, powershell, shell

I have text file location: "D:\location\test.txt" which contains XML nodes like this `<members><ID>2</ID><Name>test</Name><ID>3</ID><Name>abcd</Name></members>`.

Using Powershell I need to perform addition to node value for every contain in file, there are also node where I need perform replace.

Comment: Is the SQL language really involved here?

Comment: if we can achieve this in sql also that would also help

Comment: add a complete example of the XML please. The structure is important.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a basic approach:

```
# read XML file
$xml = [xml](Get-Content 'D:\test\test.xml')

# select node(s)
$nodes = $xml.SelectNodes("//ID")

# find all nodes with ID = 3 and replace with 4
$nodes | ? { $_.'#text' -eq '3' } | % { $_.InnerText = '4' }

# show result
$xml.members

# create new XML file
$xml.Save( 'D:\test\test_new.xml' )
```